Cyclic 3-var homogeneous inequality with 2 constraints

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be non-negative real numbers such that $ab + bc + ca = 3$. Suppose that
\[a^3 b + b^3 c + c^3 a + 2abc(a + b + c) = \frac{9}{2}.\]
What is the minimum possible value of $ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3$?

This is an HMMT problem, with a solution here.
However, it is unnatural to start with
$$ab(b+c-2a)^2+bc(c+a-2b)^2+ca(a+b-2c)^2\ge0.$$
So I want to find a solution that is easier to come up with.
Does $pqr$ method help here?

1/ Looking at the source, it asks for the minimum value. The AOPS solution is identical to the source, and states $\sum ab^3 \geq 18$.  $\quad$ 2/ That seems to be the unique non-negative real solution (with permutations).

About $ab(b+c-2a)^2+bc(c+a-2b)^2+ca(a+b-2c)^2\ge0$: I learned this trick from @d8g3n1v9 in this question.

@RiverLi But why do we need an SOS in this form? What if it was$$\sum_{\rm cyc}\left(a^2+t_1b^2+t_2c^2+t_3ab+t_4ac+t_5bc\right)^2\ge0?$$

@youthdoo Because in some approach, we need to prove that $4(a^3b + b^3c + c^3a) + ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3 + f(a,b,c) \ge 0$.  And $ab(b+c-2a)^2+bc(c+a-2b)^2+ca(a+b-2c)^2\ge0$ gives $4(a^3b + b^3c + c^3a) + ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3 + g(a,b,c) \ge 0$. Then it suffices to prove that $f(a,b,c) \ge g(a,b,c)$.

It is HMMT 2017: https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2017/feb/guts/solutions.pdf

Yes. I said that in my question statement. @RiverLi

Remark. Here is my proof. We use the trick in my answers:
P1, P2, etc.
We have
\begin{align*}
 &ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3 - 18\\
 ={}& ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3 - 18\\
  &\qquad + 
 4\left(a^3b + b^3c + c^3a + 2abc(a + b + c) - \frac92\right)\\
 &\qquad -24 (ab + bc + ca - 3)\\
 ={}& 4(a^3b + b^3c + c^3a) + ab^3 + bc^3 + ca^3\\
&\qquad + 8abc(a + b + c) - 24(ab + bc + ca) + 36\\
 ={}& ab(2a - b)^2 + bc(2b - c)^2 + ca(2c - a)^2 + 4(ab + bc + ca - 3)^2\\
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}
